# How can i fix this isuue: ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I added the current version of Openears Library(version 0.911) in my application which was already using an old version of Openears library(0.9.02).  Now I replaced all the references to the old Openears library with the new one.

However i got an error that displays

```
**Undefined symbols:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in libOpenEarsLibrary.a(PocketsphinxController.o)
      ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in libOpenEarsLibrary.a(ContinuousModel.o)
      ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in libOpenEarsLibrary.a(AudioQueueFallback.o)
      ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in libOpenEarsLibrary.a(ContinuousADModule.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**
```

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake I've done? ..
may I know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try `-lstdc++ -ObjC` in Build Settings > Other Linker Flags.

Comment: thankyou...put as a answer.then i can accept and upvote for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `-lstdc++` `-ObjC` in Build Settings > Other Linker Flags.

Answer (score 1):

go to XcodeMenu:Project->EditActiveTarget"YourApp"-> build->search "Other Linker Flags" and put

-lstdc++ -ObjC in Build Settings > Other Linker Flags and double click there and write "**-lstdc++** or **-ObjC**".this is the solution Jano given..its working fine

Answer (score 0):

OpenEars developer here. I would recommend doing this according to the instructions in the documentation at http://www.politepix.com/openears/configuring, by changing the name of the class where you are using PocketsphinxController from MyClass.m to MyClass.mm.

To brush up on this step, search for the phrase "Any class in which you intend to host PocketsphinxController and/or LanguageModelGenerator must have its suffix .m changed to .mm."

-lstdc++ for the entire project might work fine, but the framework hasn't been tested doing it that way.